# C++ - Deleting an object before returning it

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am going through the TensorFlow tutorials and while digging into the code I came across this:

```
OpDefBuilder& RegisterOp(StringPiece name) {
   VLOG(1) << "RegisterOp: " << name;
   OpDefBuilder* b = new OpDefBuilder(name);
   OpRegistry::Global()->Register([b]() -> ::tensorflow::OpDef {
     OpDef op_def;
     TF_QCHECK_OK(b->Finalize(&op_def));
     delete b;
      return op_def;
   });
   return *b;
}
```

The Register function declaration is the following:

```
void OpRegistry::Register(std::function<OpDef(void)> func);
```

The above snippet seems to be creating an `OpDefBuilder*` object with `OpDefBuilder* b = new OpDefBuilder(name);`

Then it destroys that object with `delete b;` within the lambda function passed as argument to `OpRegistry::Global()->Register(...)`. And then it returns that same object(!). Assuming that the lambda function gets called within `Register(...)` (and it does get called according to my understanding) this does not make sense to me.

I am no C++ beginner but I have never seen this kind of practice before. What am I missing here?

The full .cpp file (including the `Register(...)` definition) is [here](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/core/framework/op.cc)

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The behavior is undefined if `op_def` is returned.  You're returning a reference to a local variable.  Probably this code was barely tested for that scenario.

Comment: @up Doesn't he return it by value? `-> ::tensorflow::OpDef`

Comment: @Fireho - Yes, I missed that.  The return is for the lambda not for the entire function.

Comment: What is TF_QCHECK_OK(b->Finalize(&op_def));? That would likely have much to do with the scenario.

Comment: Usually, when you register something with someone, that something will be called *later*, not on the spot.  Otherwise, the proper name for the method should not be `Register`, it should be something else.  `Register` indicates the use of the "observer" design pattern, *not* the "visitor" design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `OpDef` sets the `initialized` member to `false`. However, the function object passed to `Register` is only called when this member is `true`. That is, the registration doesn't call the function `delete`ing the object.

Supposedly, the function gets executed later at which point the object gets cleaned up. This partice looks somewhat questionable to me but without digging a lot deeper there doesn't seem to be an obvious error.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without code for `Register`, but most likely it does not execute lambda passed to it right away. It probably stores it to execute later, as some kind of clean-up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about 90% convinced this is an actual bug.  I'm digging into it with the help of some of the folks who're more knowledgable about the op registry.  Will update.

(I believe that what's happening is that in every use of the registry, `initialized_` is false -- i.e., the ops are all registered before any lookups or other operations are done on the registry.  This path is obviously correct because the op is thrown into the deferred queue, so the delete does not take effect until later.  However, it smells like a bug if an op is registered later.  This is what I'm checking on and trying to create a test case for.)